# ionic -pollyfills fallback in custom webpack doesnt work

Tags: ionic-framework, nodemailer, ionic-native, mail-sender

hello i am currently trying to build a small project where i want to send e-mails via nodemailer. My problem is that when i try to build the project with npm run build (ng build)
I get a lot of errors because I don't seem to have polyfills configured.
This is just an excerpt, there were about 20 other module errors due to the pollyfills

```
./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/base64/index.js:3:18-45 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\Justi\Weihnachten_2023_Codes\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\base64'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
        - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
```

so I have added a custom_weback config in my package.json

```
{
  "name": "Weihanchten",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "build": "ng build ",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "config": {
    "ionic_webpack": "custom.webpack.config.js"
  },
```

in the custom webpackeg config I wrote the following to solve the problem with the pollyfills

```
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new NodePolyfillPlugin(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
      "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
      "http": require.resolve("stream-http"),
      "https": require.resolve("https-browserify"),
      "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib"),
      "path": require.resolve("path-browserify"),
      "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser")
    }
  }
};
```

Do any of you have an idea what I have done wrong?